# Why is this Haskell code so slow?

Tags: python, haskell, optimization, language-comparisons

I'm kind of new to Haskell and tried making a scrabble solver. It takes in the letters you currently have, finds all permutations of them and filters out those that are dictionary words. The code's pretty simple:

```
import Data.List

main = do
    dict    <- readFile "words"
    letters <- getLine
    let dictWords = words dict
    let perms = permutations letters
    print [x | x <- perms, x `elem` dictWords]
```

However it's incredibly slow, compared to a very similar implementation I have with Python. Is there something fundamental I'm doing wrong?

*edit: Here's my Python code:

```
from itertools import permutations

letters = raw_input("please enter your letters (without spaces): ")

d = open('words')
dictionary = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in d.readlines()]
d.close()

perms = ["".join(p) for p in permutations(letters)]

validWords = []

for p in perms:
    if p in dictionary: validWords.append(p)


for validWord in validWords:
    print validWord
```

I didn't time them precisely, but roughly it feels like the Python implementation is about 2x as fast as the Haskell one. Perhaps I should't have said the Haskell code was "incredibly slow" in comparison, but since Haskell is statically typed I guess I just thought that it should've been much faster, and not slower than Python at all.

Comment: Can you post the Python code and some benchmarks?

Comment: `words dict` is just a list, and `elem` is performing a sequential search through the list.

Comment: Strings are linked lists in Haskell. Use the text type.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted so heavily. This is a reasonable question for a beginner to have. There's not *really* enough information here to give a meaningful answer, as a lot could depend on how you're running this code. But there are some high-level improvements you could make, like using [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) and [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers). The question of why this has different performance characteristics than an equivalent Python solution is very interesting, and if you post your Python code that could help us sort it out.

Comment: Of course the answer is “because you're using the wrong data structure”.

Comment: @IanHenry: The question of why lazy linked lists perform very differently from a proper dictionary data structure isn't interesting at all. (But, FWIW, I didn't downvote this question. And I wouldn't downvote the question just because it isn't interesting.)

Comment: @IanHenry thanks for your suggestions - as a total newbie tot he language I very much appreciate all help! I looked into Set, and using it significantly improved performance. I honestly don't really need this code for anything and don't particularly care about what its run time is; I was mainly just curious if I was doing something fundamentally wrong or stupid in Haskell. Aside from using the wrong data structure, would you say there's anything else glaringly bad about my code?

Comment: Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info . It's unfortunate it isn't made more visible somehow.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, surely you're joking. Using `Text` does not address the fundamental problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm kind of new to Haskell and tried making a scrabble solver.

You can substantially improve things by using a better algorithm.

Instead of testing every permutation of the input letters, if you
sort them first you can make only one dictionary lookup and get
all of the possible words (anagrams) which may be formed from 
them (using all of them).

Here is code which creates that dictionary as a Data.Map.
There is a start-up cost to creating the Map, but after
the first query subsequent lookups are very fast.

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Control.Monad
import System.IO

main = do
  contents <- readFile "words"
  let pairs = [ (sort w, [w]) | w <- words contents ]
      dict = foldl' (\m (k,v) -> Map.insertWith (++) k v m) Map.empty pairs
      -- dict = foldr (\(k,v) m -> Map.insertWith (++) k v m) Map.empty pairs
  forever $ do
    putStr "Enter letters: " >> hFlush stdout
    letters <- getLine
    case Map.lookup (sort letters) dict of
      Nothing -> putStrLn "No words."
      Just ws -> putStrLn $ "Words: " ++ show ws
```

Map creation time for a word file of 236K words (2.5 MB) is about 4-5 seconds. Better performance is likely possible by using ByteStrings or Text instead of Strings.

Some good letter combinations to try:

```
steer rat tuna lapse groan neat
```

Note: Using GHC 7.10.2 I found this code performed the best *without* compiling with -O2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I actually did experiment with a solution very similar to the one you provided - sorting the input and the words from the dictionary and checking for anagrams that way. I used the Set structure and checked for membership with the Set.member function. That implementation actually didn't really improve my running time terrifically. Your implementation, after initialization, is incredibly fast however! I'll definitely study up on Map. Thanks again for your input - as a newcomer to the language, I hugely appreciate the help!

Comment: As a follow up - when I included a forever line in my code (the one where I sorted input and dictionary words), queries after the first were instantaneous. I guess this is because of lazy evaluation? As in the code doesn't really create the dictionary until the first query, when it actually needs it, but after it's already there for subsequent ones?

Comment: That's right. However you have to be careful with `forever` and compiler version and options - sometime the map is recomputed for each iteration. When the map is not recomputed the second and subsequent lookups are instantaneous.

Comment: While it may well be fast enough for this job, `Data.Map` is a pretty bad data structure if you're using strings (in any format) as keys. A `HashMap` would probably be better, but something more trie-like seems likely best.

Answer (score 6):

Checking if `x` is an element of `dictWords` is likely to be very slow.  I would assume that your similar python implementation stores `dictWords` in a set or sorted vector (using binary search in the latter case)?  Seems like you probably want to do the same here.

Using [this word list](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/twl06/download/twl06.txt) and the code below, the Python version runs in about 30 seconds, and the Haskell version takes 1.5 minutes.  So Haskell is slower (perhaps because it's using a linked list, which all things being equal, is slower to iterate over), but I wouldn't call it "incredibly slow" compared to Python.  Switching to use a set in either version reduces the time to under 1 second.

```py
from itertools import permutations
f = open('twl06.txt')
words = f.read().split()

print [''.join(p) for p in permutations('apricot') if ''.join(p) in words]
```

And here's the set-based Haskell code:

```
import Data.Set
import Data.List

main = do
    dict    <- readFile "twl06.txt"
    let letters = "apricot"
    let dictWords = Data.Set.fromList $ words dict
    let perms = permutations letters
    print [x | x <- perms, member x dictWords]
```

Comment: The python code stores the dictionary as a list of strings, just like the Haskell implementation. In python, to check for membership I'm using  the "in" function

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of a clear answer to your question, then, but storing dictWords as a set still seems likely to fix your run time problem

Comment: I guess I was expecting Haskell to be faster than Python since it's statically typed, so when it's 3x slower I called that "incredibly slow". It was bad phrasing on my part, I should've been clearer about the situation. Other's suggested using Set as well, and it definitely improved the running time. However, I'm still curious why lists in Haskell are slower than lists in Python. For the Python implementation, to look up a word it still has to iterate over a list. Are Python's lists just way more optimized than Haskell's? How is it possible to speed up iteration that much?

Comment: @nilcit Note that python `list`s are built-ins, which means that they are implemented directly in C as "resizable-arrays". This means that a single call to `element in sequence` will cost the interpreted overhead of a single method call, then the implementation for `list.__contains__` will kick-in and performs a C-loop over the underlying array and called the equality operator from C. so in the end CPython's `in` doesn't really have that much overhead compared to compiled languages because most of the work is done in compiled code, the only overhead are the generic comparisons.